# "which" command returns paths with two consecutive slashes

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, path, zsh

On my macOS machine, I noticed that sometimes the `which` command returns paths with two consecutive slashes. For example:

```
bash-3.2$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin//gcc
bash-3.2$ which qr
/Users/flyingblu/bin//qr
```

However, for some programs `which` returns normal paths.

```
bash-3.2$ which bash
/bin/bash
bash-3.2$ which which
/usr/bin/which
```

I tried these commands in both bash and zsh, and their outcomes are the same. 
I have never seen this in Linux systems, what is the reason for the two consecutive slashes?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show ?

Comment: I checked the PATH variable and found some paths have the trailing slash and some do not. After removing the trailing slash the outputs become normal. Thank you @mmmmmm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you need to make the directories in $PATH not have a trailing /

ie you has `/usr/local/bin/` in your path and it should be  `/usr/local/bin`